# swift 3 parse json array as key value

Tags: ios, arrays, json, parsing, swift3

i have a json, which i parse as a dictionary. Now most is simply a key value pair like "title":{"this is the title"}. The one thing bugging me is a key value pair that has an array for value.

```
"hashTags":[{"name":"pizza"},{"name":"salami"},{"name":"diet"}]
```

i do not want to use SwiftyJSON, since this is the only part i am unable to solve. What i need is to convert this value into an Array, which i can iterate. I had some approaches, they failed because they added new lines or stopped displaying äöü symbols.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `hashTags` is an array of dictionaries with `String` keys and values, cast it to `[[String:String]]`
- Iterate thru the array with a for loop and print all values for key `name`

  ```
  if let hashTags = json["hashTags"] as? [[String:String]] {
     for tag in hashTags {
         print(tag["name"])
     }
  }
  ```

It's assumed that `json` is the parent object which contains the key `hashTags`.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is using codable.

You can use **Codable** to parse Json to your desired model easily. you can check following document for more detail:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable